# Post deployment, passport login

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, web-development-server

I'm new to passport.js. 
After deployment of a website, does passport.js allow only a single user to login or does it allow multiple user logins at once without any hassle?

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes.

I cannot tell you for certain as you have not shared any code examples or error messages. Have you tried deploying and testing? In future posts, please ask a specific question or error you have and include any related pieces of code and error messages.